# PLY yacc parser : how can I handle unknown value, like imaginary numbers?

Tags: python, parsing, yacc, ply

I'm using PLY : lex and yacc to create kind of a 'bc' command : with the possibility to resolve but also to assign variables.

So I can resolve stuff like that : 
`1 + 3.12 - 4 = ?` or
`5 * 3 = ?` or
`(1 + 3) * 7 /2 = ?`

And also stuff like that, knowing that 'abc' = 10:
`(abc + 3 * abc) * 2 = ?`

But I really don't know how should I handle unknown values, or complex numbers, like imaginary numbers.

How can I handle this:
`2 * 2 * i + 3 - 1` which should be equal to `4i + 2`

I cannot think of a parsing rule to handle the imaginary number. Any help ?

My code:

**1. main code :**

```py
from global_variables import tokens
from lexer import lexer
from parser import parser


while True:
    s = input('> ')
    if s:

        # lexer.input(s)
        # while True:
        #     tok = lexer.token()
        #     if not tok:
        #         break
        #     print(tok)

        parser.parse(s)
```

**2. lexer :**

```py
from global_variables import tokens
import ply.lex as lex

t_PLUS      = r'\+'
t_MINUS     = r'\-'
t_TIMES     = r'\*'
t_DIVIDE    = r'\/'
t_MODULO    = r'\%'
t_EQUALS    = r'\='
t_LPAREN    = r'\('
t_RPAREN    = r'\)'
t_POWER     = r'\^'
t_QUESTION  = r'\?'
t_NAME      = r'[a-zA-Z]{2,}|[a-hj-zA-HJ-Z]'    # all words (only letters) except the word 'i' alone
t_IMAGINE   = r'i'                              # the word 'i' alone
t_COMMAND   = r'![\x00-\x7F]*'                  # all unicode characters after '!'

def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'\d+(\.\d+)?'
    try:
        t.value = int(t.value)
    except:
        t.value = float(t.value)
    return t

t_ignore = " \t"

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lexer = lex.lex()
```

**3. parser :**

```py
from global_variables import tokens
from global_variables import variables
from global_variables import prRed
from global_variables import prGreen
from global_variables import prLightPurple
import ply.yacc as yacc


precedence = (
    ('left','PLUS','MINUS'),
    ('left','TIMES','DIVIDE'),
    ('right','UMINUS'),
    )

def p_statement_assign(t):
    'statement : NAME EQUALS expression'
    variables[t[1].lower()] = t[3]
    print(t[3])

def p_statement_expr(t):
    '''statement : expression
                | expression EQUALS QUESTION'''
    print(t[1])

def p_expression_binop(t):
    '''expression : expression PLUS expression
                 | expression MINUS expression
                 | expression TIMES expression
                 | expression DIVIDE expression
                 | expression POWER expression
                 | expression MODULO expression'''
    if t[2] == '+': t[0] = t[1] + t[3]
    elif t[2] == '-': t[0] = t[1] - t[3]
    elif t[2] == '*': t[0] = t[1] * t[3]
    elif t[2] == '%': t[0] = t[1] % t[3]
    elif t[2] == '^': t[0] = t[1] ** t[3]
    elif t[2] == '/': t[0] = float(t[1]) / float(t[3])

    if t[0] % 1 == 0:
        t[0] = int(t[0])
    else:
        t[0] = float(t[0])


def p_expression_uminus(t):
    'expression : MINUS expression %prec UMINUS'
    t[0] = -t[2]

def p_expression_group(t):
    'expression : LPAREN expression RPAREN'
    t[0] = t[2]

def p_expression_number(t):
    '''expression : NUMBER
                 | IMAGINE'''
    t[0] = t[1]

def p_expression_name(t):
    '''expression : NAME
                 | NAME EQUALS QUESTION'''
    try:
        t[0] = variables[t[1].lower()]
    except LookupError:
        prRed("Undefined name '%s'" % t[1])
        t[0] = 0

def p_execute_command(t):
    'statement : COMMAND'
    letter = t[1].split('!')[1]
    if letter == 'h':
        prGreen("Help:")
        print("    - !p = print all variables")
        print("    - !q = quit the computor")
    elif letter == 'p':
        if variables:
            prGreen("Variables:")
            for key,value in variables.items():
                print("     {} = {}".format(key, value))
        else:
            prRed("Variables:")
            print("     There are no variables")
    elif letter == 'q':
        prGreen("Bye bye!")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Type '!h' for help.")


def p_error(t):
    if t:
        print("Syntax error at '%s'" % t.value)  
    else:
        print("Syntax error!")


parser = yacc.yacc()
```

**4. some global variables :**

```py
tokens = (
    'NAME',
    'NUMBER',
    'PLUS',
    'MINUS',
    'TIMES',
    'DIVIDE',
    'MODULO',
    'EQUALS',
    'LPAREN',
    'RPAREN',
    'POWER',
    'QUESTION',
    'IMAGINE',
    'COMMAND',
)

variables = {}

def prRed(skk): print("\033[91m{}\033[00m" .format(skk))
def prGreen(skk): print("\033[92m{}\033[00m" .format(skk))
def prLightPurple(skk): print("\033[94m{}\033[00m" .format(skk))
```

Comment: paste the code straight into the post, this will help with readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is just a reserved name here, so you can recognise it as such in the lexer (the same way as you recognise any other keyword). If you actually want `2i` to be valid, then you'll need a bit more work in the lexer, but it should be clear what's needed. (Alternatively, you could put that in the parser so that `2 i` would also be valid, but I've got to say that that looks weird to me.)

So your issue is really not a parsing issue. All you need is a complex number datatype, which Python conveniently [already has](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-complex-number). (Also see this [brief explanation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#index-12).)

Ply doesn't place any limits on semantic values. If you want to use complex numbers, just use them. (But note that Python uses `j` instead of `i` for jmagjnary numbers. That doesn't mean that you have to use them, too, but you if you want to use `i`, you'll have to do explicit number-to-string conversions.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, no library easing the management of complex numbers is authorized in my project, so I will have to implement this myself. First, I will check the links you gave me.

Comment: @cuzureau: complex numbers are just built into Python; no library is needed. But even if you had to implement complex arithmetic yourself, it's not a parsing issue. It's just semantics. You already deal with integers and floating point without any specific grammar; complex numbers are no different.

Comment: thank you very much for this answer, it helped a lot ! :) It was way easier than I thought. Are they a similar built-in (I dont' think so) or something else useful, without librairies, for storing matrices in python ?